# Recuperar response correctamente con Alamofire en Swift

Tags: json, swift, get, http-get, alamofire

Me encuentro estancado desde hace varios días en este problema y no he encontrado una solución que me haya aclarado las dudas al respecto.

Estoy intentando recibir correctamente la respuesta de un JSON de una api localhost pero no soy capaz de conseguirlo.

Para que la api devuelva algo tiene que recibir un api_token que determina el puesto de trabajo de la persona que hace la petición a través de un middleware. Os dejo por aquí la api, la respuesta (que es un array de usuarios) y la petición de Alamofire junto con el objeto Usuario y UsuarioResponse.

La Api:

```
 public function verPerfil(Request $req){
    $jdatos = $req->getContent();
    $datos = json_decode($jdatos);

    $usuario = User::where('api_token', $datos->api_token)->first();

    // $respuesta["datos"] = DB::table('users')->get();
    $empleados = User::where('puesto', 'empleado')->get();
    
    if($usuario->puesto == "directivo"){
        $respuesta["user"] = $empleados->name;
    } 
    return response()->json($respuesta);
}
```

Los structs de swift

```
struct UserResponse: Decodable {
    let user: [User]?
}

struct User: Decodable {
    let id: Int?
    let name: String?
    let puesto: String?
    let email: String?
    let salario: String?
    let biografia: String?
    let api_token: String?
    var created_at: Date?
    var updated_at: Date?
    var email_verified_at: Date?
}
```

Lo que la api devuelve

```
{
"user": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Juan x",
        "puesto": "empleado",
        "email": "lukitas@gmail.com",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "salario": 3,
        "biografia": "sinosino",
        "api_token": null,
        "created_at": "2022-01-25T10:00:43.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-26T11:01:18.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "luis",
        "puesto": "empleado",
        "email": "luisitoscomunica@gmail.com",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "salario": 3,
        "biografia": "sinosino",
        "api_token": null,
        "created_at": "2022-01-28T10:22:36.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-28T10:22:36.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "luis",
        "puesto": "empleado",
        "email": "luisitoscssomunica@gmail.com",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "salario": 3,
        "biografia": "sinosino",
        "api_token": null,
        "created_at": "2022-01-28T10:22:43.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-28T10:22:43.000000Z"
    }
]
}
```

La petición de Alamofire

```
 func getUser(api_token: String?){
    let url = "http://localhost:8888/gestor-empleados/public/api/user/verPeril"
    let parameters: Parameters =
        ["api_token" : api_token]
    
    AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseDecodable (of: UserResponse.self){
        response in
        print(response)
        if let user = response.value?.user{
            print(user)
        }else{
            print(response.error?.responseCode ?? "No error")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Cuál es el error? Porqué no usas `Codable` en ves de `Decodable`?

Answer (score 0):

La API devuelve en "salario" un `Integer` y no una `String`.
Cambia en tu `struct` `let salario: String?` por `let salario: Int` y fíjate si eso soluciona tu error.

En próximas respuestas sería de gran ayuda tener una screenshot del error o bien la transcripción del mismo.

Finalmente como dice @Bicho en comments. El protocolo `Decodable` y `Encodable` están ambos contenidos dentro del mismo protocolo `Codable` por lo que es mas fácil y sugerente usar este último.